# OpenVPN - how to disable internet access after OpenVPN hang

Tags: internet, vpn, openvpn

Time to time my OpenVPN connection hang. I want to disable all internet access automatically after VPN hang (to prevent leakage)  until I done some "action" or reconnect to VPN.

OS: Windows 7

I am not sure, but currently I have the idea and I am trying to solve this with two `.bat` files. First, that I must run after connect and second one to reestablish my internet connection without OpenVPN.

At the first `.bat` I am trying to delete default internet (primary) gateway `route delete 0.0.0.0` but the problem is that after disconnection internet works fine and default route automatically reestablish at my `route print`

Maybe somebody can suggest how to solve this problem? Step-by-step, please.

(sorry for my English, any corrections for my questions are welcome)

Answer (score 0):

A leakage problem is not really a problem for OpenVPN, which has never been designed to allow you to attain perfect privacy. In other words, preventing leakages from OpenVPN is kind of a hopeless task, even if you were to fix the issue you mention.

There are other instruments to do that. In particular, if I were you, I would consider [Tor the Onion Router](https://www.torproject.org/) and the whole operating system based on it, [Tails](https://tails.boum.org/). But even more than that, if privacy is of utmost importance to you, I would consider setting up, as a Virtual Machine inside a hypervisor, [Whonix](https://www.whonix.org/wiki/Main_Page), a specifically dedicated Operating System.